# how a user can assign tasks to another user en mass

Tags: administration, tasks

We assign tasks en mass to our sales reps. However when the rep is on annual leave they need to be able to assign their tasks en mass to colleagues. How can they do this in Salesforce?

Answer (score 0):

you can install any of these free apps for your sales reps.

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003INouEAG

http://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000018mbBEAQ

This App allows user to mass update records

Comment: have you tried it for tasks?

Comment: neither of your links, while appreciated, provide the solution required: ability for a user to mass reassign tasks to another user. The first allows a user to mass create and assign tasks - this is not the same. The second allows the mass assign of ANY record in a list view BUT tassk don't appear in a list view therefore this too is not the solution.

Comment: Ok. How about this this one https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003HU7yEAG

Comment: @Bartley Tasks do appear in a list view. It's on the home page in the calendar widget (the third button from the left under the calendar on the right hand side).

Comment: nice catch, when I referred to list view it is with the indentation of selecting one or more tasks and reassigning them...

Answer (score 0):

If you have Enterprise or Unlimited and you have permission to transfer activities owned by others, you can use the data loader. If you have not yet installed, go to Your Name-Setup-Data Management-DataLoader then download & install.

1. Export out Activities based on filtering criteria if needed. You can do this by running a report or using the Export function on the Data Loader. Make sure to export the Activity ID since this will be used to update the records.
2. Update the OwnerID field with the New Owner(User) ID -> Save the file
3. Use the Update function on Data Loader to change ownership of the activities using the new csv. file. You need to make sure that at least the record ID and owner ID fields are mapped.